# How to do the AutoIncrement ID in PHP ajax

Tags: php

I am creating a simple crud system. I can increment the ID it working well stating from 0001. but I need to start from CS0001 I don't know how to do the task

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "loyalhospital";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT MAX(cast(patientno as decimal)) id FROM patient ";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $count = $row['id'];
   $count = $count+1;
   $code_no = str_pad($count, 6, "CS0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   echo json_encode($code_no);
}
?>
```

after add the data ID is not incremented when I run the code output displayed like this **CS04**

Comment: You can not “cast” `CS0001` into a decimal, that will only result in 0.

Comment: then how get the  CS0001 like  this sir

Comment: You’ll have to use string functions to cut off the prefix `CS` first, then you can cast the remaining `000x` part into a decimal.

Comment: i don't know how to write the code please help me on this

Comment: If you don’t know which string functions MySQL has to offer, then go start by looking that up. Then try something, and report back here with the results.

Comment: But doing this (determining the “next” ID value) in a separate query is potentially dangerous to begin with, you could easily get into a situation with two (almost) “parallel” requests here. MySQL can use provide autocinrement functionality for a combined index over two columns (with the MyISAM storage engine only though), maybe that’d be a better alternative? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: $query = "SELECT MAX("CS" + cast(patientno as decimal)) id FROM patient "; but not working

Comment: Use Autoincrement column, if you want to see `CS` at the front **do that in the presentation layer**

Comment: can you write the code it is helpful for me

Comment: _“$query = "SELECT MAX("CS" + cast(patientno as decimal)) id FROM patient "; but not working”_ - well if your `patientno` column still contains `CS000x` here, then you have done nothing to fix the original problem. And feeding anything beginning with `CS` to the MAX function probably doesn’t make sense either, that expects numbers to begin with.

Comment: so i don't know how to write it sir. CS  how to cut and generated with 0001

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = (string)  $count;
$strlength = strlen($str);

switch ($strlength) {
    case 1:   
        $code_no = str_pad($count, 6, "CS000", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
case 2:
       $code_no = str_pad($count, 6, "CS00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
case 3:
       $code_no = str_pad($count, 6, "CS0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
case 4:
       $code_no = str_pad($count, 6, "CS", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
}
```

Comment: sir now out displayed successfully like this CS0006.but after add the record id is not incremented still shown CS0006. after add the record ID need to be Increment .CS0007 like that i need

Comment: $count = $count+1;